# Firebase messaging returns success, but webapp not receiving message

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the Firebase cloud messaging API and sending a message to a webapp. Everything seems to work fine, and sending the message returns success, but onMessage() which is supposed to receive the message, is never called.

GCM Connection inside chrome in `chrome://gcm-internals` is connected.
I also tried Firefox, same thing.

The response from firebase looks good:

`{'multicast_ids': [5162553035531497690], 'success': 1, 'failure': 0, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'results': [{'message_id': 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/m/...'}], 'topic_message_id': None}`

However, onMessage in the webapp is never called, and I don't know why because I'm getting no errors and everything seems fine.

Here's my JS code:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/cryptoalert/manifest.json">

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const messaging = firebase.messaging();

  messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Notification permission granted.');
      // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
      // ...
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
    });


  // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
  // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
  messaging.getToken()
  .then(function(currentToken) {
    if (currentToken) {
        console.log(currentToken);
      //sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
      //updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
    } else {
      // Show permission request.
      console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
      // Show permission UI.
      updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
    setTokenSentToServer(false);
  });

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      // ...

    });
</script>
```

And here's the server code:

```
from pyfcm import FCMNotification

push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="...")


# Send to multiple devices by passing a list of ids.
#Get registration ID from
registration_ids = ['from console.log(currentToken)']
message_title = "Uber update"
message_body = "Hope you're having fun this weekend, don't forget to check today's news"
result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=registration_ids, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)

print(result)
```

Comment: Hmm didn't do anything but ran it a day later and everything works fine?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure out why it worked the next day? I'm struggling with the same problem myself, but on Android

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. It was resolved after i published from local host with self-issued SSL to real site with trusted SSL.  Check the following steps:

- firebase-messaging-sw.js, manifest.json are in root and available
- There is a real SSL (not self-trusted)
- Code of firebase-messaging-sw.js like:

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: "830*********"
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```